# Selfhost webapi and access it from the unit test project

Tags: jmeter, asp.net-web-api2, acceptance-testing, self-host-webapi

We have a webapi project with 4 endpoints and we have a lot of acceptance tests written in JMeter. The problem is that now the JMeter file has more than 20 MB and when we have a conflict on this file while merging the branches, it is difficult to handle it correctly.

So, my question is: Is there a solution that while I run the unit tests, to selfhost somehow the api and make calls directly to my api and drop the JMeter alternative?

Comment: Is it helpful if the file is split to several smaller files?

Comment: no, it is not. even if the file would have 4mb, still there is a lot of information

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using JMeter for functional testing only you can consider switching to code-based library to make API requests, the most popular/advanced of them as of now seems to be [RestAssured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured).
2. Point 1 will require re-implementing tests from scratch, if you don't have time/budget for this you can consider refactoring your tests to remove duplicates or split your huge .jmx script into smaller parts using [Test Fragments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller). Check out [How to Manage Large JMeter Scripts With JMeter Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments) for more information.

Comment: If you look at the question tags, you will see  asp.net-web-api2, so this means that my code is in c#. Second, can RestAssured self host my api project so I can make calls to it from the unit test project?

Comment: In that case JMeter is "alien" for your project as it's Java-based and I'm kind of surprised by this choice. I strongly doubt you're capable to find C# implementation yourself so here you go: [RestAssured.Net](https://github.com/lamchakchan/)

Comment: But in order to use RestAssured.net, first I need to deploy my api, right? And later call my api? If this is teh case, than this is just a fluent interface over http client...